# PercentRelativeLayout not working

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to use PercentRelativeLayout to obtain a ratio for my widget. Even if I updated the dependecies, it doesn't seem that Android Studio recognize that Library.

Here is my gradle

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.cobaltsign.androidwidget"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.3'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.0.2'
compile 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.2.1'}

Any idea ?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to import `compile 'com.android.support:percent:23.3.0'` in your `build.gradle`. Take a look at this example :

```
 <android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">
 <ImageView
     app:layout_widthPercent="50%"
     app:layout_heightPercent="50%"
     app:layout_marginTopPercent="25%"
     app:layout_marginLeftPercent="25%"/>
```

Comment: Did my answer help you @Huiculescu

Comment: Now just added it and it makes no change.
I'm still not founding "app:layout_aspectRatio" attribute that I need.
I also added    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" to the layout in xml

Comment: could you give me what have you wrote for `app:layout_aspectRatio`

Comment: It seems like the code is working, but the autocomplete no. Thank you

Comment: yes exactly there is no autocomplete. my pleasure happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to use `app:layout_widthPercent="100%"` instead of `android:layout_width="match_parent"` in order to have ratio like 1:2 with this one `app:layout_aspectRatio="200%"`.

Resultant layout is:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:background="@color/black_25"
    app:layout_aspectRatio="200%"
    app:layout_widthPercent="100%" />
```